# Starter motor or Alternator?

Tags: car, alternator, starter, repair, motors

Can anyone offer any advice?  Got in my car on Monday and it was dead.  I turned the key and there was no noise at all, but all the lights etc came on. No clicking or anything.  I got a jump start and took it for a short spin.  Later it started fine,so I drove to the shop but when I went to start it again.. nothing. Totally dead again (apart from lights etc)  Called breakdown who bump started me and said it was a faulty starter motor, so drove it directly to garage.  They said they would check everyting before changing the motor in case it was something else.  They determined it was the problem and charged me to fit a reconditioned starter motor (£190) Two days later, same issue.  Called out rescue who said it may be an earthing problem as the battery was dead. Took back to garage who say I now need a new Alternator.  The car is only 4 years old and has 35,000 miles on the clock.  Can this be right, or being female, is there a chance I am being taken advantage of by the garage? Wanting another £229 to replace alternator...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking there's a connection issue. If the starter was dead, a jump wouldn't have fixed the issue. If the alternator was dead, which didn't charge the battery (so battery was dead because of this), the car would only have run for a short period of time until the jump which provided a partial charge to the battery, would have run out. Since the lights come on, it's not the battery. Since the battery appears charged, it's not the alternator. I cannot tell you exactly *what is the issue*, but would suggest it's a connection issue (wiring going from ignition to starter) or might be the starter relay. The alternator is way too easy to check using a multimeter while it's running (should be 13.5-14.1vdc at the battery) or if there's no check engine light while the vehicle is running, it's putting out voltage as well.

Take it to another shop, or tell them to find the real issue. It's not the alternator.